# How to create dataframe in zeppelin using python pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
Bicycletheft_raw_data = Crime_data.filter(lambda x: 'Bicycle theft' in x)
Bicycletheft_raw_data.collect()
print Bicycletheft_raw_data.count()



df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(BicycleTheft_raw_data , ['CrimeID','Month','Reportedby','Fallswithin','Longitude', 'Latitude','Location','LSOAcode','LSOAname','Crimetype','Lastoutcomecategory'])
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o742.applySchemaToPythonRDD

Comment: the error is in   df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(BicycleTheft_raw_data , ['CrimeID','Month','Reportedby','Fallswithin','Longitude', 'Latitude','Location','LSOAcode','LSOAname','Crimetype','Lastoutcomecategory'])

Comment: Can you please provide more logs and sample data? As @LostInOverflow said, there's probably a problem with your data

Comment: @T.Gawęda A guess: `Crime_data` is just `RDD[String]` and OP expects it to be automatically parsed.

Comment: conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Asmail")
crimes=sc.textFile("s3://kf7032.northumbria.ac.uk/crimes.gz")
print crimes.count()
csample=crimes.sample(False,0.1,100)
print csample.count()

Comment: def parseline2(line): 
    fields = line.split(',') 
    CrimeID = fields[0] 
    Month = fields[1] 
    Reportedby = fields[2] 
    Fallswithin = fields[3] 
    Longitude = fields[4] 
    Latitude = fields[5]
    Location = fields[6] 
    LSOAcode = fields[7] 
    LSOAname = fields[8] 
    Crimetype = fields[9] 
    Lastoutcomecategory = fields[10]

Comment: return (CrimeID, Month, Reportedby, Fallswithin, Longitude, Latitude, Location, LSOAcode,
            LSOAname, Crimetype, Lastoutcomecategory) 
Crime_data = csample.map(parseline2)
print Crime_data.count()

#BicycleTheft_raw_data = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT Longitude, Latitude, Crimetype FROM Crime_data WHERE Crimetype = 'Bicycle theft'")

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of comment.